# Escape characters for page continuation of tables

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I've been using the `\longtable` entry trying to create a log book. I've used it because I need the table to span multiple pages.

A simplified version of the document is below. Even though some of the packages aren't being used, I've included them for completeness in case I am using them incorrectly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%% PACKAGES section
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

%% Math Packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\allowdisplaybreaks
%% Date Time Pakcages
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%% Formatting Packages
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%% Citation Packages
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Table packages
\usepackage{longtable}

%% Color packages
\usepackage{color}

%% COMMANDS section
\newcommand{\logentry}[4]{\hline\\[-0.25ex]\selectlanguage{USenglish}\formatdate{#2}{#1}{#3}&{#4}\par\\[-0.25ex]}
\newcommand{\logpage}[0]{\}\{\\[-0.25ex]\selectlanguage{USenglish}\par\\[-0.25ex]}
\title{Research Log}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
%% SET section
\setlength\parindent{-10pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\maketitle
%% TABLE section
    \begin{longtable}{l p{12cm} }
        \logentry{3}{30}{2016}{Established research log after 3 hours of learning new \LaTeX}
        \logentry{6}{30}{2016}{Asked for help on \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
    \end{longtable}

    \newpage
\end{document}
```

Each entry `\logentry` correctly breaks to the next page if there is not enough space left on the remaining page. **EXCEPT** when each `logentry` spans more than 1 page, in which case it continues off the page and the next page starts with the next `logentry`.

I've tried a number of things to try to remedy this, including

1. `\newpage` command which results in an error.
2. `\pagebreak` command which results in an error.
3. Implementing a custom `\logpage` command, which a break-out of the `{}` grouping is attempted through including the string `\}\{` , but I don't think I'm using it correctly.

Am I using the escape characters in the correct context?

Is there anyway to "split" the `{}` grouping by including an "artificial" `}{` sequence?

Is there anyway to get past the problem with each `\logentry` not going beyond a page?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: q.1) I don't understand the question. q.2) No. You cannot split a longtable row over a page break because you are basically trying to break a `\parbox` and you can't break a box. TeX treats it as a box. other) Load `hyperref` last. Don't include unnecessary packages in MWEs. They just make it more difficult to help.

Comment: You have to break the row to break the page.

Comment: Just don't use a longtable! This is a job for a list environment.